# Tensorflow - How to access an element of a vector while calculating batches

Tags: vector, tensorflow, element

Now in my graph I need to calculate

```
z=a1*z1+a2*z2+a3*z3
```

where

```
z1: size=(?,5)
z2: size=(?,5)
z3: size=(?,5)
a1: size=(?,1)
a2: size=(?,1)
a3: size=(?,1)
```

Here the `?` is the size of batch to be calculated in a graph (which is unknown while building the graph).

The thing is I don't have `a1,a2,a3` yet, but I need to extract them from

```
a: size=(?,3)
```

by, kind of, `a1=a[0],a2=a[1],a3=a[2]`. But obviously `a[k]` refers to the k-th sample in the batch, so this code is incorrect.

**So how can I possibly access to the k-th element of `a`?**

Would it be correct if I do `a1 = a[:,0]`?

Comment: why are you doing individual element multiplications. You should do the matrix form : z = A.T*Z where A= [a1, a2, a3],  Z = [z1, z2, z3]

Comment: @vijaym That would be of course better. But I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't do individual multiplication but in 3D matrix form. Here is the code that you can try:

```
 # Getting the input data in right size
 batch_size = 10
 z1 = np.random.randint(0,5, (batch_size,5))
 z2 = np.random.randint(0,5, (batch_size,5))
 z3 = np.random.randint(0,5, (batch_size,5))
 z = [z1, z2, z3]
 z = np.reshape(z, (batch_size, 5, 3))
 a = np.random.randint(0, 5, (batch_size, 3))
 a = np.reshape(a, (batch_size, 3, 1))

 #Tensorflow graph 
 Z = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, 5, 3])
 A = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, 3, 1])
 out = tf.squeeze(tf.matmul(Z, A))

 with tf.Session() as sess:
    result = sess.run(out, feed_dict={Z:z, A:a})
```

I hope this is what you intend to do.